# Measurement of resistance of the Earth

Tags: resistance, ground, loading-effect

From "Learning the Art of Electronics" by T. Hayes and P. Horowitz (Cambridge University Press, 2016):[image]

If we attempt to use a digital multimeter to measure the resistance between A and B, the measured value would be hopelessly skewed due to "loading" effects [internal resistance of the multimeter is much smaller than that of the Earth, assumed to be composed of dry sand (a good insulator)]

Is it possible to measure the resistance in this example by using some instrument which has internal resistance which is much higher than the "true" resistance of the Earth ?

Comment: Why did H&H stick the probes into the North Atlantic ocean? There isn't much dry sand there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. One can measure very large resistances in the TΩ range and above with suitable instruments, for example for insulator characterization. However, such materials usually do not have a constant resistance. It strongly (orders of magnitude) depends on temperature, humidity/chemical environment and on voltage.

Therefore, the earth does not have a well-defined specific resistivity. Think of salty ocean, moist soil, granite rocks and dry desert sand.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a specific type of multimeter which can be used for such measurements in $T\Sigma$ range ?

Comment: These instruments often go by the name electrometer. @Frost